# {{ yesterday_ds }} deprecation warning, but what should I be using instead?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using the {{ yesterday_ds }} to get the date of the day before the execution date, just as the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#templates-reference) mentions.
In the logs I see a deprecation warning:

> AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'yesterday_ds' from the
> template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

But it is not clear to me what I should be using instead.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [macros.ds_add](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#airflow.macros.ds_add) `'{{ macros.ds_add(ds, -1) }}'`

Comment: I guess... seems weird though to move away to something like this. 

anyways, seems I misunderstood the run date and trigger interval anyhow, and I actually need {{ds}} ;)